# How to run a JS delayed repeated function in update( ) with a conditional?

Tags: javascript, function, phaser-framework

I'm developing a prototype game using framework Phaser with JavaScript. So, I'm trying to run a delayed function with a conditional `var isPlaying == true` in `update()` method, but it's not working. The function works, but not with the defined delayed time. It runs quickly and probably at FPS (deltaTime).

```js
update(){

   if(isPlaying){

     this.time.addEvent({delay: 2500, callback: createItem, callbackScope: this, loop: true}); 

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `update` function is fired at FPS, so you're adding a new event each frame.
Each event that you add is with `loop: true` so it will call the callback function every 2500.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you may want to put the `addEvent` at the end of the `create` function instead of `update` and then unpause it only once in update.

```js
var timer;

create() {
     timer = this.time.addEvent({delay: 2500, callback: createItem, callbackScope: this, loop: true, paused: true}); 
}

update(){

    if(isPlaying && timer.paused){
        timer.paused = false;
    }

}
```

You can find other note about Timers [here](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/timer/)